# Angular 9 Ivy, NgControl not initialized in Directive

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive, angular9, angular-ivy

I'm attempting to update my project to Angular9 / Ivy and face following problem.
I have a custom "disabledControl" directive, as described in the following Blog (https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110). I'm using it in a reactive form with an expression to enable / disable specific controls based on a combination of checkboxes.
Since the update to Angular9 / Ivy, ngControl.control is not set anymore when the @Input method set disableControl is first called.
Any hints how we can fix the proposed blog solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open issue you can find [Angular Issues](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35330)

There is a nice solution that [tweet by Alexey Zuev](https://twitter.com/yurzui/status/1225050458097704960)

The solution is to use the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook with your directive.

Here is an example of how to use the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook in order to fix the issue.

```
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[disableControl]',
})
export class DisableControlDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input('disableControl') disableControl;
  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes['disableControl']) {
      const action = this.disableControl ? 'disable' : 'enable';

      this.ngControl.control[action]();
    }
  }
}
```

[The full example by Alexey Zuev](https://ng-run.com/edit/gsCYu90ZY0aLHHuErTDE?open=app%2Fdisable-control.directive.ts&aot=true)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works like a charm! Just to be sure, you mean it's rather a workaround as a long term solution?

Comment: I just face the same problem as you do. I don't what Angular going to do with it. For me it seems like a workaround